# Why can’t a template argument be deduced in this fold implementation?

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I’m attempting to compile this code, which should print the sum of a vector, in VS 2017.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
template<typename F, typename T, typename K>
//int fold(F fun, T acc, K v) get the same error below
int fold(F fun, T acc, std::vector<K> v) 
{
    switch (v.empty())
    {
    case true: return acc;
    case false: return fold(fun, fun(*v.begin(), acc), { ++v.begin(), v.end() });
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::cout << fold([](int a, int b) {return a + b; }, 0, v);
}
```

It produces an error:

> error C2783: 'int fold(F,T,std::vector<K,std::allocator<K>>)': could not deduce template argument for 'K'

Why can’t `K` be deduced to `int` or `std::vector<int>` here? If I replace

```
template<typename F, typename T, typename K>
int fold(F fun, T acc, std::vector<K> v)
```

with

```
template<typename F, typename T>
int fold(F fun, T acc, std::vector<int> v)
```

then it compiles successfully.

Comment: You’re not returning anything in `case false:`. Turn on compiler warnings and maybe don’t use `switch` on booleans. `if (v.empty()) return acc;` is a lot more readable. (Or `return v.empty() ? acc : fold(…`)

Comment: Also, I’m not a C++ expert, but this looks like it copies the rest of the vector every time? Why not accept iterators instead of a vector, like `std::fill` for example? And you’ll want to return `T` instead of `int`.

Comment: @RyanThanks for your advice.  But I actually return acc in case false.  Can you explain something more?

Comment: @Ryan I just want to simulate a  sml function fold here so didn't pay attention to  efficiency

Comment: Why not just use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)?  It does exactly the same thing your `fold` function is supposed to do, but it works on any collection and doesn't make a bunch of unnecessary copies of the collection.

Comment: @MilesBudnek it is just a toy to practice : )

Comment: Don't try to use C++ as if were SML or Haskell. It will only lead to frustration. If you want SML you know where to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ ++v.begin(), v.end() }
```

This is interpreted as an initialiser list of two elements. The constructor that takes an initialiser list is selected, rather than the one that takes two iterators. As a result, you trying to call fold not with a reduced copy of the original vector, but with the vector of two completely different elements. But the accumulator argument doesn't match them, so template argument deduction fails.

To fix, replace this with an explicit construction:

```
std:::vector<K> { ++v.begin(), v.end() }
```

Also, use `return fold (...)` in the `false` case.

Answer (score 2):

Another way - supports every kind of container. (updated to support tuples)

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <numeric>

template<typename F, typename T, typename Container>
auto fold(F fun, T acc, Container&& v) 
{
    using value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(v))>;
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), value_type(acc), std::forward<F>(fun));
}

// spceial case for initializer_list as it can't be deduced from a braced initializer
template<typename F, typename T, class V>
auto fold(F fun, T acc, std::initializer_list<V> v) 
{
    using value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(v))>;
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), value_type(acc), std::forward<F>(fun));
}

template<typename F, typename T, class Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
auto fold_tuple(F&& f, T acc, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using expand = int[];
    void(expand{
        0,
        (acc = f(acc, std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), 0)...        
    });
    return acc;
}

template<typename F, typename T, class...Vs>
auto fold(F&& f, T acc, std::tuple<Vs...> const& tuple)
{
    using value_type = std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<Vs>...>;
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<Vs...>;
    constexpr auto element_count = std::tuple_size_v<tuple_type>;
    return fold_tuple(std::forward<F>(f), value_type(acc), tuple, std::make_index_sequence<element_count>());
}

template<typename F, typename T, class...Vs>
auto fold(F&& f, T acc, std::tuple<Vs...> && tuple)
{
    using value_type = std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<Vs>...>;
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<Vs...>;
    constexpr auto element_count = std::tuple_size_v<tuple_type>;
    return fold_tuple(std::forward<F>(f), value_type(acc), std::move(tuple), std::make_index_sequence<element_count>());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::cout << fold(std::plus<>(), 0, v) << std::endl;

    std::cout << fold(std::plus<>(), 0, { 2, 4, 6, 8 }) << std::endl;

    std::cout << fold(std::plus<>(), 0, std::array<double, 4>{ 2.1, 4.1, 6.1, 8.1 }) << std::endl;

    const double xx[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.5 };
    std::cout << fold(std::plus<>(), 0, xx) << std::endl;

    std::cout << fold(std::plus<>(), 0, std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4, 5.5)) << std::endl;

    int x = 6;
    double y = 7.7;
    long long z = 100;

    std::cout << fold(std::plus<>(), 0, std::tie(x, y, z)) << std::endl;

}
```

expected output:

```
10
20
20.4
15.5
15.5
113.7
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2eb9df5e4f60258e